# extracting the root of a tree in python

Tags: python

Hey everybody,
I've been trying to find a built-in function for extracting the root of a tree in python,
I haven't found something like that and I've been trying to build one of my own but I couldn't build something generic to fit all my needs. 
Does anyone have something prepared or perhaps know how to extract this information from the tree structure in python?

thanks

Comment: Last I checked, Python doesn't have a generic built-in tree structure, so you're going to have to explain what tree you're talking about.

Comment: Tree implementations in/for Python: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/0.3.0 http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/rbtree.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to roll your own:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, p=None):
        self.parent = p
        self.children = []

n1 = Node()
n2 = Node()
n1.children.append(n2)
n2.parent = n1
```

Of course you would want to have methods like `addChild` that would manage the `.children` and `.parent` attributes of the involved objects automatically.

Then you could write a method

```
def findRoot(node):
    p = node
    while p.parent != None:
        p = p.parent
    return p
```